# How to concurrently execute functions

Tags: elixir

I am new to FP and elixir I am trying to execute below functions simultaneously. But this is stuck on read(). I tried `Task.async` and `spawn_link` and passing functions in it but did not work

```
defmodule MyFile do


def start() do

read()
write()


#Task.async(read())
#Task.async(write())
end



def read() do
case 1 do
  1 -> IO.puts "this  is one"
  2 -> IO.puts "this is two"
  _ -> IO.puts "this is dont care "
end
   read()
end


def write() do

case 1 do
  1 -> IO.puts "THIS IS ONE OF WRITE"
  2 -> IO.puts "THIS IS TWO OF WRITE"
  _ -> IO.puts "this is dont care "
end
   write()
end


end
```

It is printing `"this  is one"` on console so `write()` function in `start()` is never getting executed as the control is inside `read()`. How can I somehow start both and execute simultaneously in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were nearly there with `Task.async/1`. The only thing is you need to supply an [anonymous] function as its argument, while you *called* the function instead.

```rb
defmodule RW do
  def start() do
    #          ⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓ HERE
    Task.async(&read/0) # or fn -> read() end
    Task.async(&write/0)
    :ok
  end

  def read(counter \\ 10) do
    IO.puts "this is one"
    unless counter <= 0, do: read(counter - 1)
  end

  def write(counter \\ 10) do
    IO.puts "THIS IS ONE OF WRITE"
    unless counter <= 0, do: write(counter - 1)
  end
end
```

Results in (I explicitly terminate is after 10 executions):

```rb
iex> RW.start
# this is one
# THIS IS ONE OF WRITE
# this is one
:ok
# THIS IS ONE OF WRITE
# this is one
# THIS IS ONE OF WRITE
# this is one
# THIS IS ONE OF WRITE
# THIS IS ONE OF WRITE
# this is one
# THIS IS ONE OF WRITE
# this is one
# THIS IS ONE OF WRITE
# this is one
# THIS IS ONE OF WRITE
# this is one
# THIS IS ONE OF WRITE
# this is one
# THIS IS ONE OF WRITE
# this is one
# THIS IS ONE OF WRITE
# this is one
```

Note that `RW.start/0` exited with `:ok` after 2 outputs from `read/1` and 1 output from `write/1`. You don’t need a controlling process to execute tasks.

Comment: _Sidenote:_ unlike the solution with the controlling process, this one is **truly concurrent**. Note the two consequent `"THIS IS ONE OF WRITE"`.

Comment: Thanks thats cool! can you tell me the like other answer suggest process. For what I should really use process?

Comment: Well, `Task.async/1` does indeed spawn a process. Answering your question, unless you know you need a process, you are to avoid it. That simple, and later you’ll meet situations when the process is needed and you’ll understand this yourself. For instance, persisting the state always requires the process.

Answer (score 1):

You should start your `read` and `write` functions with another processes. After that, they send the msg back to main process like below to print it simultaneously. Below code can help you understand more.

```
defmodule Doan do

def start() do
  current = self()
  spawn(Doan, :read, [current])
  spawn(Doan, :write, [current])
  loop()
end

def loop do
  receive do
    {:read, 1} -> IO.puts "this  is one"
    {:write, 1} -> IO.puts "THIS IS ONE OF WRITE"
    {:read, 2} -> IO.puts "this is two"
    {:write, 2} -> IO.puts "THIS IS TWO OF WRITE"
    _ -> IO.puts "this is dont care "
  end
  loop()
end

def read(pid) do
  send pid, {:read, 1}
  :timer.sleep(500)
  read(pid)
end

def write(pid) do
  send pid, {:write, 1}
  :timer.sleep(500)
  write(pid)
end
end
```

and result on shell:

[image]

Comment: thanks for your detailed explanation this is same as ping pong example. However I read that we should not use process when not really required. For example keeping it simple for calculator implementation instead putting them in GenServer. So I felt we don't need process here. Do you know a way I can concurrently run functions here ?

Comment: It seems that in Elixir/Erlang, we have no method to do this jobs without using process

Comment: @bxdoan sure we can, see my answer for the implementation spawning two `Task` instances without any issue.